# Is there a nice way to evaluate $\iiint_{E}\, \frac{dx\,dy \,dz}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+(z-b)^2}}$ where $E:x^2+y^2+z^2\leq a^2$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

> Is there a nice way to evaluate $$\displaystyle\iiint_{E}\, \dfrac{dx\,dy\,dz}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+(z-b)^2}}$$ where   $E:x^2+y^2+z^2\leq a^2$ with
>     $0<a<b$

If I use the standard spherical coordinates **(Is there a better transformation?)**

$$x=p\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta) $$

$$y=p\sin(\phi)\sin(\theta)$$

$$z=p\cos(\phi)$$

$$|J|=p^2\sin(\phi)$$

$$\iiint_{E}\, \frac{dx\,dy \,dz}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+(z-b)^2}} $$

$$=\int_{\phi=0}^{\pi}\,\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\,\int_{p=0}^{a}\, \frac{p^2\sin(\phi)\,dp\,d\theta \,d\phi}{\sqrt{p^2\sin^2(\phi) + (p\cos(\phi)-b)^2}}$$

$$=\int_{\phi=0}^{\pi}\,\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\,\int_{p=0}^{a}\, \frac{p^2\sin(\phi)\,dp\,d\theta \,d\phi}{\sqrt{(p-b\cos(\phi))^2 + b^2\sin^2(\phi)}}$$

Which I'm finding bit difficult.

Comment: look at my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/474499/59379) to a similar question for 3 ways to evaluate this integral. you probably want method 3 which is the most elementary one.

Answer (score 1):

Fubini split w.r.t. the $z$-component. Let $J$ be the integral to be calculated. I will use 
$B(0,r)$ for a ball centered in $0$ with radius $r$ (in the dimension that 
can be extracted from the context.) 
Then:
$$
\begin{aligned}
J &=
\iiint_{B(0,a)}\frac 1{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+(b-z)^2}}\; dx\; dy\; dz
\\
&=
\int_{z\in B(0,a)}dz
\iint_{(x,y)\in B(0,\sqrt{a^2-z^2})}\frac 1{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+(b-z)^2}}\; dx\; dy
\\
&=
\int_{-a}^a dz
\int_{r\in[0,\sqrt{a^2-z^2}]}
\int_{t\in[0,2\pi]}
\frac 1{\sqrt{r^2+(b-z)^2}}\; r\; dr\; dt
\\
&=
\int_{-a}^a dz
\int_0^{\sqrt{a^2-z^2}}
2\pi\Big(\ (r^2+(b-z)^2)^{1/2}\ \Big)'\; dr
\\
&=
2\pi
\int_{-a}^a dz\;
\Big[\ (r^2+(b-z)^2)^{1/2}\ \Big]_0^{\sqrt{a^2-z^2}}
\\
&=
2\pi
\int_{-a}^a dz\;
\Big[\ (a^2-z^2+(b-z)^2)^{1/2}-(0^2+(b-z)^2)^{1/2}\ \Big]
\\
&=
2\pi
\int_{-a}^a dz\;
\Big[\ (a^2-2bz+b^2)^{1/2}-(b-z)\ \Big]
\\
&=
2\pi
\left[\ -\frac 1{2b}\cdot \frac 1{3/2}(a^2-2bz+b^2)^{3/2}
+\frac 12(b-z)^2\ \right]_{-a}^a
\\
&=
\frac {2\pi}{3b}\Big[\ (b+a)^3-(b-a)^3\ \Big]
-
\pi\Big[\ (b+a)^2-(b-a)^2\ \Big]
\\
&
=
\frac {2\pi}{3b}\cdot 2a^3
=
\frac {4\pi\, a^3}{3b}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Check using [sage](http://www.sagemath.org):

```
sage: var( 'r,t,z,a,b' );
sage: assume(a>0)
sage: assume(b>a)
sage: J = integral( integral( integral( r/sqrt(r^2+(z-b)^2), t,0,2*pi ), r,0,sqrt(a^2-z^2) ), z,-a,a )
sage: J.canonicalize_radical()
4/3*pi*a^3/b
```

---

Here is the computation of the integral for its version "without the square root in the denominator"...

$$
\begin{aligned}
J &=
\iiint_{B(0,a)}\frac 1{x^2+y^2+(b-z)^2}\; dx\; dy\; dz
\\
&=
\int_{z\in B(0,a)}dz
\iint_{(x,y)\in B(0,\sqrt{a^2-z^2})}\frac 1{x^2+y^2+(b-z)^2}\; dx\; dy
\\
&=
\int_{-a}^a dz
\int_{r\in[0,\sqrt{a^2-z^2}]}
\int_{t\in[0,2\pi]}
\frac 1{r^2+(b-z)^2}\; r\; dr\; dt
\\
&=
\int_{-a}^a dz
\int_0^{\sqrt{a^2-z^2}}
2\pi\cdot\frac 12\Big(\ \ln(r^2+(b-z)^2)\ \Big)'\; dr
\\
&=
\pi
\int_{-a}^a dz\;
\Big[\ \ln(r^2+(b-z)^2)\ \Big]_0^{\sqrt{a^2-z^2}}
\\
&=
\pi
\int_{-a}^a dz\;
\Big[\ \ln(a^2-z^2+(b-z)^2)-\ln(0^2+(b-z)^2)\ \Big]
\\
&=
\pi
\int_{-a}^a dz\;
\Big[\ \ln(a^2-2bz+b^2)-2\ln(b-z)\ \Big]
\\
&=
\pi
\left[\ -\frac 1{2b}(a^2-2bz+b^2)(\ln(a^2-2bz+b^2)-1)+2(b-z)(\ln(b-z)-1)\ \right]
_{-a}^a
\\
&=
\pi
\left[\ 
-\frac 1{2b}(b-a)^2(2\ln(b-a)-1)
+\frac 1{2b}(b+a)^2(2\ln(b+a)-1)
\right.
\\
&\qquad\qquad
\left.
+2(b-a)(\ln(b-a)-1)
-2(b+a)(\ln(b+a)-1)
\ \right]
\\
&=
2\pi\ln(b+a)\cdot\left[\frac 1b(b+a)^2-2(b+a)\right]
-
2\pi\ln(b-a)\cdot\left[\frac 1b(b-a)^2-2(b-a)\right]
+2\pi a
\\
&=
2\pi\frac 1b(b^2-a^2)\ln\frac {b-a}{b+a}+2a\pi\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: You left out the square root in the denominator.

Comment: Oh... as i saw it, it was without the square root, but now i am no longer sure of this... Is there a history of the changes of the question somewhere?! (I will retype to fit...)

Comment: Hmmm. I only saw it with the root, but the other response has no root. Maybe it was changed?

Comment: I checked the revisions: Yes, it was changed.

Comment: I am confused. shouldn't $z$ vary $-
\sqrt{a^2-r^2} $ to $\sqrt{a^2-r^2}$?

Comment: We let *first* $z$ take values from $-a$ to $a$. For each fixed value $z_0$ of it, the corresponding section of the 3D ball of radius $a$ with the plane $z=z_0$ is a disk of radius $\sqrt{a^2-z_0^2}$. We now let $(x,y)$ vary in this disk, compute first the integral with respect to $(x,y)$, using polar coordinates in the disk, then the integral w.r.t. $z$.

Answer (score 0):

I would try cylindrical coordinates:
$$
\begin{cases}
x=\rho\cos\phi\\
y=\rho\sin\phi\\
z=z
\end{cases}
\implies
\begin{cases}
x^2+y^2=\rho^2\\
dx\,dy=\rho\,d\rho\,d\phi
\end{cases}
$$

Which should give you:
\begin{align}
\iiint_E \frac{\rho}{\rho^2+(z-b)^2}d\phi\,d\rho\,dz&=\iint_E \frac{2\pi\rho}{\rho^2+(z-b)^2}d\rho\,dz\\
&=\int_{-a}^a\int_0^{\sqrt{a^2-z^2}} \frac{2\pi\rho}{\rho^2+(z-b)^2}d\rho\,dz\\
\end{align}

To me, it seems a little easier now.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with your final integral, do four things:

1) Since the integrand does not depend on $\theta$, perform the $\theta$ integration, which puts a factor of $2\pi$ in front.

2) Multiply out and simplify the things in the denominator.

3) Make the change of variables $p = b\, r$.

4) Make the change of variables $u = \cos\phi$.

After all that, we are left with:

$$
2\pi b^2 \int_0^{a/b}dr\, r^2 \int_{-1}^1 du\, \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - 2 r u + r^2}}
$$

Note that the quantity $1/\sqrt{1 - 2 r u + r^2}$ is the [generating function for Legendre Polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials):

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - 2 r u + r^2}}
\;=\; \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P_n(u)\, r^n
$$

Also note that

\begin{equation}
\int_{-1}^1 du\, P_n(u) \;=\;
\begin{cases}
2 & n = 0\\
0 & n\ne 0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Putting this all together:
\begin{align}
2\pi b^2 \int_0^{a/b}dr\, r^2 \int_{-1}^1 du\, \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - 2 r u + r^2}}
&=
2\pi b^2 \int_0^{a/b}dr\, r^2 \int_{-1}^1 du\,\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P_n(u)\, r^n\\
&=
4\pi b^2 \int_0^{a/b}dr\, r^2\\
&= \frac{4\pi}{3}\,\frac{a^3}{b}
\end{align}

I like to check things numerically in case of mistakes, and having done so in Mathematica I find that this expression matches the numerical integration of your *final* integral for all the values of $b \ge a$ that I tried.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to slice things up is to cut the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2\leq a^2$ into spherical shells centered at $(0,0,b)$.

First of all, observe that the desired result is the integral over the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2\leq a^2$ of the reciprocal distance to the point $(0,0,b)$. This is the motivation for slicing things up into shells centered at $(0,0,b)$.

In the picture below the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2\leq a^2$ is pink, and a few of the shells over which we’ll integrate are indicated by the grey arcs (and one heavier black arc) within the pink area.

[image]

The point of this approach is that the reciprocal distance to $(0,0,b)$ is constant on each shell.

Parameterize the shells by the $z$-coordinate at which they cross the blue line below. The $z$-values run from $-a$ to $a$. The points of the “shell at $z$” are at distance $b-z$ from $(0,0,b)$, so the answer to the original question is

$$\int_{-a}^{a}{\frac1{b-z}}\left(\mbox{ surface area of shell at $z$ }\right)\,dz$$

The shell at $z$ is a “spherical cap,” and it’s been known since Archimedes’ time that the surface area of a spherical cap of height $h$ cut from a sphere of radius $r$ is $2\pi r h$. A bit of geometry and algebra shows that the spherical cap that is this problem’s “shell at $z$” has height $\dfrac{a^2-z^2}{2b}$, and as previously observed, is part of a sphere of radius $b-z$. Therefore the answer to the original question is

$$\int_{-a}^{a}{\frac1{b-z}}2\pi(b-z)\left(\dfrac{a^2-z^2}{2b}\right)\,dz=\frac{\pi}b\int_{-a}^{a}\left({a^2-z^2}\right)\,dz=\frac{4\pi a^3}{3b}$$