# Evaluate the triple integral by transforming to spherical coordinates.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Evaluate the integral by transforming to spherical coordinates
$ \iiint_S [(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 + (z-c)^2]^{\frac{-1}{2}} dxdydz$ , where S is a solid sphere of radius R and centre at origin, and $(a,b,c)$ is a fixed point outside this sphere.
I tried via spherical coordinates but it's going too complicated.

Comment: You don't by any chance know about the mean value property of harmonic functions, do you?

Comment: @Saager You mentioned `I tried via spherical coordinates but it's going too complicated.` Please consider showing us what you have tried and where you are stuck. We can help you better that way.

Comment: $x=rsin\theta cos\phi, y=rsin\theta sin\phi, z=rcos\theta$.

Comment: $x=rsin\theta cos\phi, y=rsin\theta sin\phi, z=rcos\theta$.   Now $dxdydz=r^2sin\theta dr d\theta d\phi$. Now it becomes $\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\pi \int_0^R [r^2+a^2+b^2+c^2-2r(asin\theta cos\phi +bsin\theta sin\phi +c cos\theta)]^{\frac{-1}{2}} r^2 sin\theta dr d\theta d\phi$

Comment: Next what to do. It's going very complicated

Comment: @Saager: You should be editing your question and adding all the information and details to it, rather than making comments.

Comment: Small suggestion for you: By rotating the solid sphere around the origin, you may without changing the answer assume the point $(a,b,c)$ is at $(0,0,A)$, where $A=\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}$. You might then want to do the integral with respect to $\theta$ first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Triple Integral $ \iiint\limits_S\frac1{\sqrt{\left(x-a\right)^{2}+\left(y-b\right)^{2}+\left(z-c\right)^{2}}}\;dx\;dy\;dz $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/474441/triple-integral-iiint-limits-s-frac1-sqrt-leftx-a-right2-lefty-b-rig)